# Highlighting html element when radio button is checked w/o js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to modify an html item (i.e. a div) when a radio button is selected without using js. Here is the markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="myRadioBtn" class="btn-radio" type="radio" name="name" value="value"/>
    <div class="box">BOX</div>
</div>
```

I would like for "box" to change its color once "myRadioBtn" is selected. I know I could use js/jQuery but if possible, I'd like to do it in CSS only. Is that possible?

Comment: Not that I am aware of but am curious to see other replies + very curious behind the reason why you want to do it through CSS and not JS?

Comment: You could try a sibling selector with a pseudo-class.  `#myRadioBtn:checked + div.box { background-color: red; }` but I don't know that this is very cross-browser friendly.

Comment: Mainly I would like to find out if it's possible at all. If it is, better performance would be an added bonus.

Answer (score 6):

```
#myRadioBtn:checked + .box {
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tyEys/

I'm not able to check if it works in IE8.

Edit: You could replace the + with a ~ to select only the .box that comes immediately after the radio. So if you had 2 boxes after the radio, the second one won't be affected.

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it. See my comment above.

Comment: Or maybe not. I left a comment explaining that I ended up using " ~ " but it disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + .box {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HmVW8/)**